# Problem 23 chapter 5 PMA Rudin (point a)

Tags: real-analysis

The function $f$ defined by $$f(x)=\dfrac{x^3+1}{3}$$has three fixed points, say $\alpha, \beta, \gamma,$ where $\alpha\in (-2,-1), \beta\in (0,1), \gamma\in (1,2).$ For arbitrarily chosen $x_1$, define $\{x_n\}$by setting $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.

(a) If $x_1<\alpha$, prove that $x_n\to -\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

(b) If $\alpha<x_1<\gamma$, prove that $x_n\to \beta$ as $n\to \infty$.

(c) If $\gamma<x_1$, prove that $x_n\to +\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

I have some problems with a).

**My sketch proof:** I proved  that if $x_1$ is arbitrarily  real number such that $x_1<\alpha$ then sequence $\{x_n\}$ is decreasing. But how to prove that $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded? Because if we prove that then $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}x_n=-\infty$.

Can anyone help with that please?

Comment: Hint:  the limit of a sequence is $-\infty$ if, for every $M < 0$, there exists an $N > 0$ such that for every $n > N$, $x_n < M$.

Comment: @heropup, I know that. But I can't see it can help to me? Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: Do you know that it has 3 fixed points or is that part of what you are trying to prove?@RFZ

Comment: @Giovanni, I guess that we know that it has 3 fixed points.

Comment: @Nicholas: these are the (approximate) roots according to wolfram alpha: $x_1 = -1.879 \in (-2,-1)$, $x_2 = 0.34 \in (0,1)$ and $x_3 = 1.53 \in (1,2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you proved that it is decreasing you are done. Indeed, $\{x_n\}$ is monotone, hence it either converges to a finite $L$ or it diverges to $-\infty$. Suppose by contradiction that it converges to $L > -\infty$. Then you would have that $L$ is a fourth fixed point for $f$.

Comment: Dear Giovanni! Ohhh great hint, really great! If $x_n\to L$ then $f(x_n)\to f(L)$ because $f$ is continuous but $f(x_n)=x_{n+1}$. Hence $f(L)=L$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking :)

Comment: Dear Giovanni. Just now I will solve point b). If there are problems can I ask you please?

Comment: I am not sure what the policy is exactly, but I think that since this question was specific about part $(a)$ it is advisable to ask another question on the site if you need help with something else. This will give more visibility to your new question. I glad I could help :)